# How do you migrate local database changes to testing server?

Tags: php, mysql

I FTP source code files and then take a dump of the database (with Drop table option selected) and overwrite live testing server database. But the problem with this is it takes my `"junk" testing data` along with some `required default data`. Then I have to manually delete the rows which are not required so that I can give client a clean state. It'd be ideal if I do it through a script which drops existing table and data and create new tables with required default data.

The idea I had was -

```
$table1 = "sql to create table1";
mysql_query($table1);
$table1_data = "sql to insert default data for table1"; 
mysql_query($table1_data);
```

and so on for 20+ different tables ...

There must be a better way to handle this. What would you say?

** Update **

Is is possible to write all the queries in one variable and run it - 
e.g.

```
$sql =" 
   Drop If exists table1
   create table1 ....
   Insert Into table 1....
   Drop If exists table2
   create table 2
   Insert into table 2 
   .....
   .....
   .....
";
mysql_query($sql);
Is there a way to achieve something like above???
```

Comment: Look into *database migrations*, they're a typical way to handle this.

Comment: how can you differentiate default from junk?

Comment: You can set default values in MySQL for each field. If by required default data you mean rows, then why don't you make an export of that data (without creating the tables) and load it when needed?

Comment: @khaled_webdev - e.g. table "roles" - default roles "Admin", "Manager", "Staff", "Guest" - when I am developing and testing on my local - I add "RoleTest1", "Role2Smith", "Role3Joe" etc -- so when I am sending it for client testing I only want to show first four roles. Also Admin here is a "system" role which must be there in order for client to login as an admin and test the site.

Comment: @Robert  - I do that too - but what I am asking for is multiple rows of data for some tables - see my example above.

Comment: @user1421214 have you a copy of the original database? (may be is evident but hwo know .. )

Comment: @khaled_webdev - Yes I thought about that too - but its not just the data sometime table structure changes too - so if I had a script I'd just run that on my local and live whenever I wanted to start afresh!

Comment: @user1421214 i m not sure but if you do a structure dump for your edited base (just structure) and import into into temporary database, dump data from original DB, import original data into temporary DB (the edited one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get any answer from the community so I am sticking to my own solution ..

I created an array of queries -

```
$queries[] = 'drop table';
$queries[] = 'create table';
$queries[] = 'Insert into table';
```

and then run each of then in a for loop. Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Some PHP frameworks allow you to set up *fixtures* that populate the required tables with predefined data. If you're not using any such framework, I suggest you create a dump of only the tables you need for testing, leaving the others intact.

If you have shell access, you can create a partial dump with `mysqldump` by specifying the tables you want to export right after the database name:

```
mysqldump --host=localhost --username=myuser --password databasename table1 table2 table3 >databasename.sql
```

Comment: I already mentioned that I take a full export of the database and import it on the server but I still have to delete unwanted data manually so I am looking for better method. I had a look at Symfony once where you can create .yml files etc but as I am not using any framework - plain php solution is what I am looking for. Thx